# accessing BIO via FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, friend

When I examine a particular user (friend) via the Graph API, I can see their bio. How do I access the BIO with FQL?

I seem to be able to access the few items that the Graph API does return with FQL, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Per: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

You would use `fql?q=SELECT about_me FROM user WHERE uid=me()`

Or if you want friend's about_me/bio, then run the following:

'fql?q=SELECT about_me FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1=me())'

Here's some of my results.  Notice some nulls and some blanks and some filled in:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "about_me": ""
    },
    {
      "about_me": "aspiring rocket scientist"
    },
    {
      "about_me": ""
    },
    {
      "about_me": "Enjoying Life"
    },
    {
      "about_me": null
    },
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the same field... I get a null result for a user that *does* show a bio via the Graph API.

Comment: It's exactly the same with me.  I have a very unique text in my bio and that unique text is only in my bio.  I get that unique text in the about_me column of the FQL user object.